# Does Objective-C auto generate setter and getter?

Tags: objective-c

I am calling a method from other class, as below

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) CalculatorModel *calculatorModel;

double result = [self.calculatorModel result:operator];
```

however this method doesn't received the message from the caller. Until I wrote the getter my self

```
- (CalculatorModel*)calculatorModel {
    if (!_calculatorModel) _calculatorModel = [[CalculatorModel alloc]init ];
    return _calculatorModel;
}
```

and it works. why, I remember once you did @property, the Objective-C will generate setter and getter automatically. Am I wrong?

Thanks

updated: [image]

Comment: Yes, that's the point of a property.

Comment: you are right, but the synthesized getter wouldn't lazily allocate an instance of the requested property like you did. this is why the message 'result' was sent to nil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. However you still have to initialize the property by using `[[Class alloc] init]`. Like we set the property for `NSMutableArray`, `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *anArray;` and before you are using `anArray` you have to init it as `_anArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];`

the `- (CalculatorModel*)calculatorModel` method is called Lazy instantiation, which will take over the `[[Class alloc] init]` job before calling, this will give help on both performance and memory control.

Answer (score 3):

> Does Objective-C auto generate setter and getter?

Well, rather the compiler, but **yes, recent versions of Clang have this feature.** You don't need to manually synthesize properties anymore.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya added "anymore" to make it perfect :P

Comment: You can also say "This is available from XCode4.4+" :)

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I can't - it's unrelated to the version of Xcode.

Comment: Then he may ask I have XCode3.2, can i use that clang.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Then I reply, 'irregardless of the version of your Xcode installation, clearly depending on the *compiler version* only, you may or may not'.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I hope too. He should, definitely.

Comment: @TomH : So you are very much updated!!! Yesterday only I downloaded XCode4.6, Even AppCode uses same LLVM/clang compiler

Comment: @AnoopVaidya I prefer the answer from xxd, and I think the point is the Lazy instantiation.

Comment: @TomH: Your title says something else, your question says something else. He picked another point to discuss!!!

Comment: @TomH No need to downvote my answer, it's technically correct.

Comment: @H2CO3: I didn't, downvote needs 125 reputation, however I saw you have -4 reputation from my question. Anyway, still thanks for answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like You don't need to manually synthesize properties anymore from xCode4.5.The IDE will help you do it.But terrible thing is if you open your project on xCode4.3 or xCode4.4, it will not work,lots of warning will appear,then you should add the code by yourself .

Comment: well.Got your point.The getter and setter just return the pointer's value of property.If your property isn't init,it's still nil, then , return nil to you. it's always return what you give it,case you give it nothing.